# Move a <div> via css to the end

Tags: html, css

I have to build mobile views for an existing website. HTML is like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="right_column">
    <img .....>
  </div>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

right_column has a float: right.

For mobile view I'd like to move right_column to the end of the container. Trying it with position:absolute doesn't work well, because the container doesn't grow.

Any ideas?

Alex

Comment: Can you provide us with a jsFiddle? with all html and css that you use now?

Comment: There's no way of telling how to achieve this unless we know the following : how big is the browser view on the mobile device, what does the rest of the page look like and what does the rest of the css look like?

Comment: seriously you'll get an easier experience with bootstrap a looooot of people use it. there a whole part deidcated to what you'r trying to do. http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html

Comment: This is a very common problem. Rather than provide you with a plain jane answer, here's the theory behind it that will give you absolutely all the info needed to to create what is called a **Responsive Design**. | 

Daddy of responsive design: http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design
 | 
Demo: http://d.alistapart.com/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-mini.html
 | 
More blabber: http://www.copyblogger.com/mobile-responsive-design-101/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2BaUZ/ 

The <img> should be placed within the border.

It would be better if the right column was at the end in HTML. But there are several hundreds of articles that have to be rearranged... So I'd prefer to have some CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If the height of the container is fixed you can play around with `padding-bottom` and use `position: absolute; bottom: XX` but I am afraid you cannot guarantee the height of the container.

Another option would be to put the `div` at the end of your HTML and make it float to the right in normal view, that's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Use table display properties. `display: table` on the container, `display: table-footer-group` on the right column.

Beware, this might have some fun side effects on the container.

http://jsbin.com/abivis/1